# Magento Multistores base url retriving issue in adminpanel

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, multistore, admin-panel

I have created multistore in Magento. In admin panel i tried to get this multistore base url:

Below code i tried :

```
Mage::getStoreConfig("web/secure/base_url", 2);
Mage::getStoreConfig("web/secure/base_url", 5);
Mage::getStoreConfig("web/secure/base_url", 3);
```

Also i tried below code  :

```
Mage::app()->getStore(2)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK); 
Mage::app()->getStore(3)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK); 
Mage::app()->getStore(5)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK);
```

If i enterd this code in the site, the page was not loaded.

My Code in admin-panel(header.phtml) :

```
  <p class="super">
            <?php echo $this->__("Logged in as %s", $this->escapeHtml($this->getUser()->getUsername())) ?><span class="separator">|</span><?php echo $this->formatDate(null, 'full') ?><span class="separator">|</span><a href="http://golinks.magento.com/CE15" onclick="this.target='_blank'" class="go-try"><?php echo $this->__('Try Magento Go for Free') ?></a><span class="separator">|</span><a href="<?php echo $this->getLogoutLink() ?>" class="link-logout"><?php echo $this->__('Log Out') ?></a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <?php 
             if(Mage::helper('multistoreconfig')->multistore_config_enable()) {
                echo "<select class='no-changes' id='list_store' onchange=\"popWin(this.value,  '_blank')\"><option value=''>-- Select Store --</option>";
                foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $websiteid => $website) {
                    foreach ($website->getGroups() as $group) {
                        $stores = $group->getStores();
                        foreach ($stores as  $storeId => $store) {
                            $data = $this->checkMultiStoreConfigurInStoreId($storeId);
                            if( $data[0]['sub_directory'] || $storeId == 1) {
                                $option_url = Mage::getStoreConfig("web/secure/base_url", $storeId);
                                // $option_url = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK);
                                echo "<option value='". $option_url ."'>";
                                echo Mage::helper('multistoreconfig/data')->getStoreName($storeId);
                                echo "</option>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
             echo "</select>";
            ?>
    </p>
```

Any help would be appreciation.

Comment: I think your issue is in your code. The 'multistoreconfig' part imo. if you remove your whole code and just insert the test code below, I'm pretty sure you will get your store urls.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you place this code?

For me it works just fine in
`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/index/notifications.phtml`

with the following code inserted at the end of the file:

```
<?php
echo    Mage::getStoreConfig("web/secure/base_url", 1);
echo '<br />';
echo    Mage::getStoreConfig("web/secure/base_url", 2);
?>
```

Comment: I have placed in this code "app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/header.phtml".
I am tring like store switch in admin panel.

Comment: This works for me also. Have you tried my code snippet? You may have some error in it if it prevents the entire page from loading.

Comment: I have tried ur code in header.phtml.., Same error the page was not loaded.

Comment: That is strange. Does your backend work without your code? Can you paste the current content of your header.phtml?

Comment: Yes working fine, with out above code. Also i have updated my question.

Comment: I get an error message: Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Multistoreconfig_Helper_Data' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/local.magento.de/app/Mage.php on line 547

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22666/discussion-between-vijay-s-and-tecjam).